# Relationship between (reduced) cohomology of suspensions and cohomology of $X \times S^1.$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Let $E$ be a generalized cohomology theory, let $X$ be a space, and let $i: X \to X \times S^1$ be induced by the inclusion of a basepoint into $S^1$. If $p$ denotes the projection $p: X \times S^1 \to X$, we obtain a splitting
$$E^{\ast}(X \times S^1) \cong \operatorname{im}(p^{\ast}) \oplus \operatorname{ker}(i^{\ast}),$$
since $p \circ i = id_X$.

I want to understand how this cohomology group is related to the $E$-cohomology of the suspension.
More precisely, the projection
$q: X \times S^1 \to \Sigma X_+$ induces a map in cohomology, but I am not sure what it gives me.

A claim I've seen is that it induces an isomorphism $$\tilde{E}^{\ast}(\Sigma X _+) \to \operatorname{ker}(i^{\ast}).$$
It is not clear to me why this is true, nor why we need reduced cohomology here.

Any ideas (or references) for a proof?